# Sreen reader inconsistencies when aria-labelledby applied

Tags: html, accessibility

I had some strange behaviour where the chrome screen reader was reading labels twice, I inadvertently "fixed" it and I'm not sure the fix was correct.

In the code example below, I added an `aria-labelledby` which referenced the input id and it stopped reading it twice which I am utterly confused by.  I meant to have `aria-labelledby` referencing the label id but when I did that it started reading the labels twice again:

```html
<div>
  <label for="placeOfBirth" id="placeOfBirth-label">Place of birth<span><em>(such as town, city or province)</em></span></label>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" value="" id="placeOfBirth" name="placeOfBirth" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="placeOfBirth" aria-describedby="placeOfBirth-error" maxlength="100">
  </div>
  <div id="placeOfBirth-error" aria-hidden="true" role="alert"> </div>
</div>
```

Then the problem is that the label is not being read when the element has focus so I reverted it to this but the labels are read out twice when the form is first rendered:

```html
<div>
  <label for="placeOfBirth" id="placeOfBirth-label">Place of birth<span><em>(such as town, city or province)</em></span></label>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" value="" id="placeOfBirth" name="placeOfBirth" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="placeOfBirth-label" aria-describedby="placeOfBirth-error" maxlength="100">
  </div>
  <div id="placeOfBirth-error" aria-hidden="true" role="alert"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which screenreader do you use? Which browser? Is it different with another browser?

Comment: this mac voiceover on chrome

Comment: Did you end up getting it worked with Adam's answer? I'm having the same issue in the same environment but unfortunately, Adam's answer didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

The screenreader read it twice because it first reads the `label` elements, and then it reads the alternative text for the `input`.

When you set the `aria-labelledby` to the `input` own id, the alternative name for the `input` becomes blank, which is bad.

By setting the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute on the `label` and using `aria-labelledby="placeOfBirth-label"` this might remove the problem, as `aria-hidden` has no influence for elements referenced by `aria-labelledby`.

I would add that screenreader users are used to this kind of behavior and the repetition of the text is not a major problem for them